# How to return data to variable after ajax call success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP file returning data in required array format to my FlotChart, it's working.
Now I'm trying to get this result in my script using ajax, however I cannot see result on global variable, as described below:

```
myJS.js   
var EcomDashboard = function() {
    return {
        init: function() {

        var dataEarnings = NULL;

        $.ajax({
            url:"operation.php",
            dataType: "text",  
            success:function(data) {
                alert(data); //show my array [ [1, 20],[2,30],[3,14] ] 
                dataEarnings = data;
            }
        });

        alert(dataEarnings); //showing "NULL" but I need [ [1, 20],[2,30],[3,14] ]

        ...
```

What is the correct way to assign to my variable date Earnings the array [[1, 20], [2.30], [3.14]]?

Comment: Can't you use Json instead of Ajax? i use it almost like that and it usually works Since Ajax is asynchronos, the code reaches the alert at the same time (if not before) the ajax function, with Json, it "waits" for the function to finish and then run the rest

Comment: @PauloLima [JSON](http://json.org/): _(JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format._

Comment: FlotChart isn't a default json format, but I could try... How do you get result using JSON?

Comment: Well idk about FlotChart, I usually use this with MVC but its kind of like this


`var dataEarnings = NULL;
$.getJSON("<pathtomymethod>", function(data) {
 //succes - data loaded
 alert(data); //show my array [ [1, 20],[2,30],[3,14] ] 
 dataEarnings = data;
});
alert(dataEarnings);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url:"operation.php",
  dataType: "text",  
  success:function(data) {        
    doSomthingOnComplete(data);
  }
});

function doSomthingOnComplete(data)
{
  // do here your work
}
```

Comment: yes but this one i tries and working very fine

Comment: Guy, it works great! I dont need to create a new JS with this solution... tks!

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is an async language, it means it won't wait the http request to finish to execute the next line. you will have to assign the variable inside the `success` block.
the alert shows null is becauseit got executed before the $.ajax http request line finishes.

may be you can do this using a callback:

```
dataAccess.js    
var ecomDashboard = function() {

            init: function(callback) {

            var dataEarnings = NULL;

            $.ajax({
                url:"operation.php",
                dataType: "text",  
                success:function(data) {
                    callback(data);
                }
            });
         }
    }

controller.js
    ecomDashboard.init(function(data){
          // data contains the array result
        // do your stuff

    })
```

event better:
since jquery 1.5 there is incorporated promise interface<del>, and .success is going to be deprecated.</del> edited: thanks to Kevin B

so with promise:

```
    dataAccess.js    
    var ecomDashboard = function() {

                init: function(callback) {

                var dataEarnings = NULL;

                return $.ajax({
                    url:"operation.php",
                    dataType: "text"
                });
             }
        }

    controller.js
        ecomDashboard.init().done(function(data){
//do your stuff
alert(data);
}).fail(function(error){
//do stuff when error
});
```

Comment: note that success: is not deprecated, but .success is. Very important distinction. There's nothing wrong with using `success: function () {}` other than the fact that using the promise signature provides more functionality, it is not deprecated.

Comment: @kevinB thanks for pointing out edited

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because that `alert(dataEarnings)` is executing before your ajax request resolves.  The first letter in the AJAX acronym is Asynchronous. So, ultimately your data is being set properly you are just trying to access it before the asynchronous call completes.