# Ajax firing fail() even after updating value to python flask view

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, flask

I am trying to send data from webpage to python flask using ajax and receiving nothing as response

**1. The data is saved to dictionary in javascript in 'requestPayload' variable. And the 'callApi' function is called. code is below**

```
const registerinfo = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/register_info'

console.log(JSON.stringify({requestPayload}))
result = callApi('POST', registerinfo, {'data': JSON.stringify(requestPayload)})
console.log(result)
```

**2. The 'callApi' further calls ajax function. code is below**

```
function callApi(method, url, data){
    $.ajax({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done((data) => {return data})
    .fail((xhr,textStatus, errorThrown) =>{ alert(xhr.status + "      "  + textStatus + "       " + errorThrown)})
}
```

**3. The flask function takes the data from ajax and returns nothing. code is below**

```
@app.route('/register_info')
def registerInfo():
    request_payload = json.loads(request.form['data'])
    print(request_payload)
    return ('',204)
```

**The output of the 'console.log' in javascript and print function in python flask is below**

[output in the console in javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pElz6.png)

and

[output of the print function in flask function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmnOe.png)

The problem is I am getting the ajax.fail() and not firing ajax.done function and I am not able to find what the error is, Please help me with this.

Comment: You should stringify the JSON 

```result = callApi('POST', registerinfo, JSON.stringify(requestPayload))```

Comment: I have stringified and sent the data, even the python flask function works But the ajax .done function is not working.

Comment: Okay, I think the problem is with returning the data in the `.done` method because it is like a promise you cannot return data without a call back so you can try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679371/how-to-return-data-to-variable-after-ajax-call-success

Answer (score 0):

The ajax was not working because the access control allows origin not done true.